# Facing problem for these auxiliaries!

Tags: grammar

"A great deal of thoughts(are/is) into the designing of the auditorium".
Is it "is" or "are"?give explanation for the correct answer.My book says it is "is".I think its a typing mistake of my book.

Comment: It sounds weird either way.  I'd say *A great deal of **thought went** into the **design** of the auditorium*.

Comment: I agree with snailboat - idiomatically, it's always "a great deal of **thought**", never *thoughts*.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the options sounds correct. It should be something like this:

Past:

> A great deal of **thought** was put into **designing the auditorium**.
>
> A great deal of **thought** was put into the **design** of the auditorium.

Present:

> A great deal of **thought** is being put into **designing the auditorium**.
>
> A great deal of **thought** is being put into the **design** of the auditorium.